# client side certificate installed on ios 16 are not being sent by browsers on that device when a server requests for a identity cert

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority, ios, client-side

I have a client side certificate from cloudflare (non-root) that i install on our devices in order to gain access to our sites that ask for a client side certificate from browsers. This works perfectly well on desktop browsers on linux, windows and even on mobile browsers on android devices.
BUT on ios devices the certificate is not sent nor am i presented with the choice of certificates to send to the server when i use chrome and safari on the ios device. The certificate is installed on the device but is not verified of course since it is a non-root certificate and the CA is a private CA for which I do not have a root certificate.

What is the way to get the installed certificates show up in the browser prompt as usual so that it can be sent to the server?
Does ios need the certificates to be trusted? Why should ios want that for client side certificates is beyond me but in that case what could be the way out (since we dont have the root certificate for the CA that issued the client side certificate)?

This is driving me crazy and the whole organization is at my neck to get it working as there are many ios users in the organization. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: installing the pfx with the key

Comment: Previous deleted comment (edited) read: Just making sure: when you install the client cert on iOS, are you installing just the certificate, or the certificate plus the private key? The certificate alone is useless for the client. -- Follow-up: Do you get any error messages or similar? Can you access the list of certificates and keys in the Keychain Access app or anything similar? (I know how to do this on MacOS but have never tried on iOS.) You might have to enable the cert for client authentication or something like that.

Comment: I am installing the cert + pvt key and Yes it is enabled in ios. @CBHacking